# Is there any dedicated Stack Exchange site for iOS devices and iOS applications?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Is there any dedicated Stack Exchange site for iOS devices and iOS applications, like [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) for Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is for you.

From its [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic%27):

> Ask Different is for **Apple enthusiasts and power users**. If you have a question about ...
>
> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)
> - third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products, including scripting or automation of and on Apple hardware/software.

Answer (score 5):

Not for iOS specifically, but there is https://apple.stackexchange.com/, known as **Ask Different**.

> Ask Different is a question and answer site for Apple enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to useful questions about Apple hardware or software.

Answer (score 3):

If are looking at bottom of the site. then you can find out couple of site links in footer.

[image]

[image]